# Set foreign key associations through migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, referential-integrity

I have the following diagram of tables for my project:

- Campeonato = Championship (which is an event)
- Especial = Special (which is an event too)

[[image: diagram]]

I would like to generate Grand Prix that belongs to Championships. The relationship is a 1:n Association. One Grand Prix always belongs to one championship or to one "Special Event".

I am making the models and writing the migration with its columns, but I do not know how to express the association inside the migration.

I have the following migration's code:

```
class CreateGrandPrixes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :grand_prixes do |t|
      t.datetime :gp_date
      t.integer :max_slots
      ## Relationship 
      t.belongs_to :championship, index: true
      t.belongs_to :special, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I do not know if this is the correct way to reference the foreign key.

To sum up, I have three entities:

- Championship
- Special
- GPs

GPS belongs to at least one championship or one special. I would like to know the right way to show that on my migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `t.references :champtionship`

And tailor it to your needs with options:

- foreign_key
- null

But you could also just add an integer column called `champtionship_id` and add the foreign key manually using `add_foreign_key`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I do have more "problems". My GP could belongs to Championship or Special entity.

How could I set if a GP is from a Championship or Special? 

I mean you are saying that I could do the following:

GP_Table

| id_gps | id_champ | id_track |   gp_date     | max_slots

but it could also be a Special so 

Could I introduce another colum as reference:

| id_gps | id_champ | id_special | id_track |   gp_date     | max_slots


Sorry I am a little bit lost in here :S

Comment: Perhaps you want to look into polymorphic associations. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this solution?

```
class CreateJoinTableChampionshipGrandPrix < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :championships, :grand_prixes do |t|
      # t.index [:championship_id, :grand_prix_id]
      # t.index [:grand_prix_id, :championship_id]
    end
  end
end
```

And repeat this process for Special & GPs?

Answer (score 0):

If your GPS belongs to at least one championship or one special but not both. You could use the `polymorphic` association.

Following would be your models:

```
class Campeonato < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'Campeonato'
  self.primary_key = 'id_evento'

  has_one :gp, as: :eventable
end

class Especial < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'Especial'
  self.primary_key = 'id_evento'

  has_one :gp, as: :eventable
end

class Gp < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'Gps'
  self.primary_key = 'id_gp'

  belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true
end
```

And following would be the corresponding migrations:

```
class CreateCampeonato < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table 'Campeonato', id: true, primary_key: 'id_evento' do |t|
      #add other fields
    end
  end
end

class CreateEspecial < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table 'Especial', id: true, primary_key: 'id_evento' do |t|
      #add other fields
    end
  end
end

class CreateGps < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table 'Gps', id: true, primary_key: 'id_gp' do |t|
      t.string :event_type # to store the class name (ex: Campeonato or Especial)
      t.integer :event_id # to store the primary_key of Campeonato or Especial
      #add other fields
    end
  end
end
```

Refer to [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) for more info.